# Ubuntu Wireshark Portable on USP

Tags: 16.04, usb, wireshark, portable

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running on my PC. I installed Wireshark and it is working well. The issue is PC RAM which is 4 GB.  After a short while capturing UDP packets the machine gets very slow and, after 30 minutes, the PC will hang and is no longer able to run.

I want to install Wireshark on my external hard disk which is 1 TB. There is a portable Wireshark for Windows, which can be installed on any external device connected through USB port; but how can I install a portable Wireshark for Ubuntu?

Appreciate if anyone can provide me some useful info. or show me where I can download such a package.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the portable wireshark through wine: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11235

I am not sure whether you need to install winpcap libraries to ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
can you please give a brief explanation on how should I do that? I have dused Ubuntu in a very basic level and not sure how to "run Wiresshark through Wine".
Appreciate if can provide more info on it.

Comment: Install wine via command: sudo apt install wine, then run wireshark portable with wine wireshark.exe . Change the wireshark.exe to the actual name of the executable file.